# Mapping servlet to both mydomain/myservlet/ and mydomain/myservlet/index.html

Tags: tomcat, servlets, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have a servlet, myservlet, which in the web.xml file under servlet-mapping I have mapped to the url-pattern, index.html. Requests for http://mydomain/myservlet/index.html invoke the servlet fine. However requests for http://mydomain/myservlet/ invoke a pop-up login window. I tried the pattern /* instead, but this destroyed the path to my stylesheets etc, and even if I put these all in the top level would cause problems with local hard-coded help files.

Is there any way to use the URLRewriteFilter (or anything else) so that an incoming request for http://mydomain/myservlet or http://mydomain/myservlet/ remaps to http://mydomain/myservlet/index.html but nothing else is touched?

(I'm testing the servlet on Tomcat on my local machine, although it's being deployed on an old Sun Webserver.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 3.0//EN" "http://tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite3.0.dtd">

<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
        <from>^/myservlet[/]{0,1}$</from>
        <to>/myservlet/index.html</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

The `[/]{0,1}` part is just like doing `[/]?` to signify zero or one match in regex, but using the `?` qualifier does not work in the url rewrite filter.

Comment: Thanks Matt. However it doesn't seem to work, but I have only  just installed the URLrewrite stuff, and haven't been able to check the test rewrite as I can't get localhost to work. I'm running a version of Sun Java Server on a Linux box, which uses port 80 for servlets. However I do all my testing on my Mac with a local Tomcat server, where localhost obviously works fine.

Comment: I would try to get a simple rule to work (like `<from>^/test.html$</from><to>^/index.html$</to>`) and my suggested rule to work in your local tomcat, and then apply the same rules & filters on your Linux box.

Comment: The URLrewrite installs OK on local Tomcat, although I couldn't check the problem as no problem exists on Tomcat. Looking at the Sun server reload output on the command line I see it doesn't recognize the filter etc tags in the web.xml, so it seems likely the engine doesn't work with that server. I suspect I'm wasting my time and that it would be better to migrate to a standard Tomcat server asap, as has been the plan. (Delayed by circumstances outside my control. Thanks again Matt.